# Como descobrir e exibir elementos repetidos dentro de um Array em Swift 4

Tags: swift-playground

Sou novo no StackOverFlow e também novato em programação Swift.

Será que alguém mais experiente poderia me informar como eu faço para identificar elementos repetidos dentro de um array sem usar Extensions?

Apenas usando o for e if.

Obrigado pela ajuda e abraços a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Tem duas maneiras de compreender esta pergunta, se você quer saber a quantidade que determinado elemento se repete em um array ou então quantas vezes cada elemento se repete.

Digamos que você tenha uma array de Strings:

```
 var names = ["George", "Fabio", "Maria", "Fabio", "Eugenia", "Maria", "Maria"]
```

Se você quiser saber a quantidade de repetições que cada elemento tem dentro de desse array você pode percorrer esse array e guardar dentro de um dicionário cada repetição onde a chave é o item e o valor é a quantidade que esse item repetiu como:

```
//Dicionário para guardar quantas vezes cada nome foi repetido 
var counts: [String: Int] = [:]

//Percorre todos elementos no array
for name in names {
   //Ele adiciona mais 1 ao contador do nome se estiver repetido
   counts[name] = (counts[name] ?? 0) + 1
}
//Imprime o resultado de todas repetições 
print(counts)
```

O resultado é

```
["Maria": 3, "George": 1, "Eugenia": 1, "Fabio": 2]
```

Caso você queira saber somente quantas vezes um elemento esta repetido no array é preciso somente um for e comparar:

```
var nameToCount = "Maria"
var result = 0

for name in names{
   if name == nameToCount{
      result = result + 1
   }
}
print("O nome:",nameToCount,"Repetiu",result, "x")
```

Resultado:

```
O nome: Maria Repetiu 3 x
```